# How to call multiple contracts from single sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a situation where I should call multiple contracts from a single wso2 esb sequence basing on the condition like if one contract gets success the other contract need to be executed or if the first fails another contract need to be executed.

Can anyone help me in achieving this. If any skeleton sequence please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Filter+Mediator) in your sequence to check conditions..
Or else, use [router mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Conditional+Router+Mediator) Here is a sample on how to use them.[1](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Filter+Mediator)

[1](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Filter+Mediator) http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Sample+1%3A+Simple+Content-Based+Routing+%28CBR%29+of+Messages